# Single interpolation and scope work weird in ionic 3

Tags: interpolation, ionic3

As to `full_address`, my `console.log` is undefined even though I set it to `:string="hahaha"`.
I think that's why single interpolation doesn't work, I set `full_address` right after first `console.log` and second `console.log` works. why is it?

[image]

Comment: You dont need to set it as `public full_address` is can be just `full_address:string = "hahaha"`

Comment: ok...anyway it dosen't work

Comment: try `console.log()` in the constructor. this is a weird issue. Ive never had this problem